# Automate responses to prompts in an npm/npx command line install

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting, command

I want to automate installation of [Redocly](https://redoc.ly/docs/cli/#installation) (API documentation generator) via the command line. A Redocly project is generated with npx (`npx create-openapi-repo`). The install process triggers four prompts (shown in quotes; followed by the answers I need to input). Some have processing in between.

```
"Do you already have an OpenAPI/Swagger 3.0 definition for your API? (y/N)" y
"Please specify the path to the OpenAPI definition (local file):" test.yml
"API Name:" My API
"The following folders will be created: openapi and docs. You can change them by running create-openapi-repo Proceed? (Y/n)" Y
```

The problem is that commands that seem to enable automatic completion for script files are not enabling it with the Redocly npx install, at least through my attempts.

Failed attempts, among many others, include the following (one in Windows Command Prompt and the rest in Bash). Some include answers to only three of the four prompts because I rarely got past the second one.

#### Attempt

cmd.cmd:

```
npx create-openapi-repo
```

Command prompt (Windows Command Prompt):

```
C:\Source\api-docs>(echo y && echo test.yml) | cmd.cmd
```

Command prompt results:

```
C:\Source\api-docs>npx create-openapi-repo
Welcome to the OpenAPI-Repo generator!
? Do you already have an OpenAPI/Swagger 3.0 definition for your API? Yes
test.yml
? Please specify the path to the OpenAPI definition (local file):
<ends>
```

#### Attempt

cmd.sh:

```
read -n 1 -p "Do you already have an OpenAPI/Swagger 3.0 definition for your API? (y/N)" Y
read -n 1 -p "Please specify the path to the OpenAPI definition (local file):" test.yml
read -n 1 -p "API Name:" My API
```

Command prompt (Bash):

```
$ ./cmd.sh
```

Command prompt results:

```
Welcome to the OpenAPI-Repo generator!
? Do you already have an OpenAPI/Swagger 3.0 definition for your API? Yes
? Please specify the path to the OpenAPI definition (local file):
```

#### Attempt

Command prompt (Bash)

```
printf 'y\test.yml\My API' | npx create-openapi-repo
```

Results same as above.

#### Attempt

```
printf '%s\n' y test.yml 'My API' | npx create-openapi-repo
```

Results same as above.

#### Attempt

cmd.txt:

```
y
test.yml
My API
```

Command prompt (Bash):

```
npx create-openapi-repo < cmd.txt
```

Results same as above.

Is anyone aware of how to accomplish this? If it matters, the goal is to execute deployment of Redocly in an Azure DevOps pipeline. The pipeline offers the ability to run commands in Bash, Windows Command Prompt, or PowerShell.

Comment: Look into `expect`.

Comment: `create-openapi-repo` co-author here:
We can definitely add support for passing JSON config with answers.
Can you please open an issue and describe your use case here: 
https://github.com/Redocly/create-openapi-repo/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option is to use `expect` as suggested by Shawn.

If you are sure of the time between two prompts (for example, less than 10 seconds), you can try things like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{
echo y
sleep 10
echo test.yml
sleep 10
echo My API
} | npx create-openapi-repo
```